# Covariant Return Types: return another inheritance class pointer

Tags: inheritance, types, covariant-return-types

I have this code:

```
class Base{
    virtual Base* Foo() = 0;
}

class A: public Base{
    B* Foo(){}
}

class B: public Base{
    A* Foo(){}
}
```

And it give error when compile:
**overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant**
How can i fix it ?